# Regex Pattern Matching Difficulty

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having issues with understanding pattern matching. I've figured it out to a point but I'm having a lot of trouble with this specific pattern I need to match.

Requirements:
Check for the format of the user name. It should start with a letter
followed by letters, numbers, and periods. A user name should be at
least 6 characters long but no more than 12.

This is what I have so far:

```
var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
var pos = user.search(/^[A-z](?=.*?[A-z])(?=.*?[0-9])\./);
```

Comment: First add 'if (user.length <= 12)' and you've solved half of the issue :)

Comment: Are consecutive periods forbidden?

Comment: I have that setup, the only issue at this point is checking for the letters,numbers, and period.

Comment: Ok, well just in case, here's a regex that prohibits multiple periods (but doesn't check length) `/^[A-z][A-z0-9]*(\.?[A-z0-9]+)*$/`. Length is easier to check with code.

Comment: **Do not use the range `[A-z]` in a regex.**  It matches several punctuation characters in addition to the uppercase and lowercase letters it's intended to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should start with a letter followed by letters, numbers, and periods. A user name should be at least 6 characters long but no more than 12.

So you want to allow a string that starts with a letter and has at least one dot or number and is between 5 and 12 characters.

In that case, use the following:

```
^[A-Za-z](?=.*\d.*)(?=.*[.].*)[A-Za-z\d.]{5,11}$
```

- `^` match start.
- `[A-Za-z]` a letter.
- `(?=.*\d.*)` positive lookahead - the following string contains at least 1 digit.
- `(?=.*[.].*)` positive lookahead - the following string contains at least 1 dot.
- `[A-Za-z\d.]{5,11}` the rest of the string contains between 5 and 11 letters, digits and dots (the total string between 6 and 12).
- `$` match end.

Note: -

- `?=` the forward lookup does not affect the match position, so the match will continue at the second character.
- `?=` an AND is implied between the forward lookups, so both need to be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern

```
var pattern = /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.0-9]{5,11}$/


^ matches beginning of file. 
[A-Za-z] = matches first letter
[A-Za-z.0-9] = Matches a-z both A-Z and a-z the . (dot) character and numbers 0-9
{5,11} = tells that the last character "group" should have between 5 or 11 occurrences. witch makes the total string between 6 and 12 characters long. 
$ = matches end of string
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Javascript to do the match

```
var pattern = /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.0-9]{5,11}$/

//assuming the var username contains the username
if(username.match(pattern)){
     alert("Valid pattern");
}
else{
     alert("Invalid pattern")
}
```

Comment: I put that pattern into the program but it only throws an alert if the first character isn't a letter.

Comment: check this fiddle for how you could do this check http://jsfiddle.net/tj6cx/ My pattern is tested and is working. So if it doesn't for you, you probably have an error in your code!

Comment: I just ran it using only letters and still got valid pattern.

Comment: [A-z] should be avoided when matching capital and lowercase letters, as this pattern will also match [, /, ], ^, _, and `.  Using [A-Za-z] is safer.

Comment: you didn't specify that it couldn't be only letters.

Comment: @PhilipG it can't be only letters, but it doesn't match the pattern when I input only letters. I still get that it is a valid pattern when I use only letters.

Comment: Yes. of course since thats also a valid password according to your specification in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.]{5,11}$
```

This one should do for you as you do not have any constrain about minimum occurrence for any character.